# Trouble creating a "RESET" button for a GUI Change Calculator

Tags: java, user-interface

I recently started working with GUIs in Java. The code that I am currently working on is a "CHANGE CALCULATOR". The program asks the user to input how much money a consumer paid for a product (ex. $5.00), how much money a product costs (ex. $2.99), and finally spits out the amount of change that is to be returned to the customer and a way to return that amount (ex. "You owe the customer $3.01. This could be returned using 1 toonie, 1 loonie...). I have been trying to implement a "RESET" button that would start the code again from the beginning at any point but have been unable to do so. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

One other issue that I am also facing comes with handling a certain exception. My code needs to be run in a certain order (ex. the "PAID" button must be clicked before the "COST" button). I want an error message to display on the user interface if this happens.

As aforementioned, I am new to GUI and any suggestions would be lovely.

Thank you!

The code below is the change calculator logic

```
    package FinalProject;


public class ChangeCalculator {
    /*
     * Since this is only a candy shop, I've decided that the program will calculate
     * up to $20 worth of change
     */


    String Answer;

    double[][] breakDown = { { 100.00, 0 }, { 50.00, 0 }, { 20.00, 0 }, { 10.00, 0 }, { 5.00, 0 }, { 2.00, 0 },
            { 1.00, 0 }, { 0.25, 0 }, { 0.10, 0 }, { 0.05, 0 } };

    double finalchange; // The amount of money that must be given back


    public double finalone(double x, double y) // Calculation to determine the remainder
    {

        finalchange = Math.round((x - y) * 100) / 100.0; // Math.round is used to keep the double up to two
                                                                    // decimal places
        System.out.println("You owe the customer $" + (finalchange)); // First statement

        return finalchange;
    }

    public String Answer() // A final answer with all the new values is printed
    {

        calculateChange();

        String Statement = ("You could give the required change using:\n" + getIntValue(breakDown[0][1])
                + " hundred dollar bills. \n" + getIntValue(breakDown[1][1]) + " fifty dollar bills. \n"
                + getIntValue(breakDown[2][1]) + " twenty dollar bills. \n" + getIntValue(breakDown[3][1])
                + " ten dollar bills. \n" + getIntValue(breakDown[4][1]) + " five dollar bills\n"
                + getIntValue(breakDown[5][1]) + " toonies.\n" + getIntValue(breakDown[6][1]) + " loonies.\n"
                + getIntValue(breakDown[7][1]) + " quarters. \n" + getIntValue(breakDown[8][1]) + " dimes. \n"
                + getRoundedIntValue(breakDown[9][1]) + " nickels."); // 3/4 cents are rounded to a nickel; 1/2 cents
                                                                        // are ignored

        return Statement;

    }

    private void calculateChange() {

        for (double[] denomination : breakDown) {

            // Calculate # occurrence per denomination
            denomination[1] = finalchange / denomination[0];

            // Re-calculate finalchange by finding the remainder
            finalchange = finalchange % denomination[0];

        }

    }

    private int getIntValue(double d) {
        return new Double(d).intValue();
    }

    private int getRoundedIntValue(double d) {
        return (int) Math.round(d);
    }

}
```

The code below is the GUI and main method

```
package FinalProject;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI extends JPanel {
    private static JPanel keys;
    private JButton clear;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton pay;
    private JButton cost;
    private JTextField display;
    private static JTextArea textarea;

    String payment = "";
    String costs = "";
    String[] cal;
    double one = 0;
    double two = 0;
    String check = "";
    double total = 0;

    ChangeCalculator value = new ChangeCalculator();

    public GUI() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        display = new JTextField();
        add(display, "North");
        display.setSize(122, 330);
        display.setEditable(false);

        keys = new JPanel();
        keys.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

        keypad("7");
        keypad("8");
        keypad("9");
        keypad("4");
        keypad("5");
        keypad("6");
        keypad("1");
        keypad("2");
        keypad("3");
        keypad("0");
        keypad(".");

        clear = new JButton("CLEAR");
        keys.add(clear);
        class ClearButton implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                display.setText(" ");
            }
        }
        ActionListener listen = new ClearButton();
        clear.addActionListener(new ClearButton());

        pay = new JButton("PAID");
        keys.add(pay);
        pay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                cal = display.getText().split("\\/");
                payment += cal[0];
                textarea.setText("The customer paid: $" + payment + "\n \nNow enter the cost of the product");
                cal = null;
                display.setText(null);
            }
        });

        cost = new JButton("COST");
        keys.add(cost);
        cost.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                cal = display.getText().split("\\/");
                costs += cal[0];
                one = Double.parseDouble(payment);
                two = Double.parseDouble(costs);

                if (value.finalone(one, two) > 0) {
                    textarea.append("\n \nThe product costs: $" + costs + "\n\nYou owe the customer $"
                            + (value.finalone(one, two)));

                    textarea.append("\n\n" + value.Answer());
                }

                else {
                    textarea.setText("ERROR! The customer has not payed enough. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        });

        reset = new JButton("RESET");
        keys.add(reset);
        class add implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //What code should go here to make the entire program restart?
            }
        }
        ActionListener c = new add();
        reset.addActionListener(new add());

        add(keys, "South");

    }

    private void keypad(final String Label) {

        try { //I don't know where to place the exception
            class buttons implements ActionListener {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent add) {
                    display.setText(display.getText() + Label);
                }
            }

            JButton button = new JButton(Label);

            button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            keys.add(button);

            ActionListener listen = new buttons();

            button.addActionListener(listen);

            textarea = new JTextArea(5, 5);
            textarea.setSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
            add(textarea);

        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            textarea.setText("ERROR! Please remember to press the 'PAID' button before the 'COST' button." + e);
        }
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Change Calculator");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(450, 600);

            frame.getContentPane().add(new GUI());

            JMenuBar men = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu instructions = new JMenu("RULES");
            JMenu Keypad = new JMenu("Keypad");

            instructions.add("Do NOT run the program if the user has not payed enough money for a product.");
            instructions.add("Do NOT press the 'COST' button before the 'PAID' button. ");
            instructions.add("Do NOT enter multiple decimals into the calculator. ");

            textarea.setText(
                    "Welcome to Change Calculator! \n \nPlease refer to the 'RULES' tab in the top corner to see \nthe restrictions of the program. \n \nTo start, please enter the amount of money the user paid for the product using \nthe keypad below. \n\nAfter entering the amount of money the customer owes, press the 'PAID' button. \n\nFeel free to press the 'RESET' button if you enter an incorrect value when running the code!");
            textarea.setEditable(false);

            men.add(instructions);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, men);

            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general you should try to avoid adding so much. It's easier for us to help if you come up with a simpler example demonstrating the problem. What exactly do you mean by "start the code again from the beginning"? If you mean remove the GUI and rebuild it then I would suggest there are probably better ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I just meant that the program will restart from the intro page.